# Apache Flume Spooling Directory duplicate events

Tags: file, duplicate-data, flume

Apache Flume User Guide says spooling directory source may duplicate events under certain circumstances.
Here is the line from docs:
"Despite the reliability guarantees of this source, there are still cases in which events may be duplicated if certain downstream failures occur."

What are those cases? Especially if we are using durable channel like file channel i dont see any reason to duplicate events occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You described the file channel as durable. You didn't say once and only once delivery.

Flume's guarantee is at least once delivery. Batches will be resent on failure. This can lead to duplicate events.

Example: node 1 is sending events to node 2. All the events are sent and node 2 acknowledges receipt. However. Network conditions are such that that message is lost. Node 2 has stored the batch but node 1 will resend it. Thus, duplicate events.

Comment: Hi i will accept your answer as correct. But just one more, If i use single agent/node then i think it is not possible to produce duplicate events since channels and sinks runs in transactional manner?

Comment: A failure writing to the sink (database, HDFS) etc will also rollback. If you are sure that the sink always rolls back correctly on failure then you might be okay. You can also get a rollback from the client to the agent which may yield duplicates.